# Differentiate class type of QML objects in C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a custom QML rectangle that I want to differentiate from the built-in QML rectangle when accessing from C++:

```
// CustomRectangle.qml
import QtQuick 2.3

Rectangle {
   width: 10
   height: 10
   // property bool dummy // line A
}
```

When I instantiate a C++ class that needs to know about the object's type, calling `QMetaObject::className` returns `QQuickRectangle`. However, if I add a property by uncommenting line A, the `QMetaObject::className` is now `CustomRectangle`.

How can I differentiate a class like this from QQuickRectangle without adding properties?

Answer (score 2):

You can access the object by using `objectName` property. For example:

**QML**

```
Rectangle {
   width: 10
   height: 10
   objectName: "MyObject"
}
```

**C++**

```
QQuickItem *item = view.rootObject()->findChild<QQuickItem*>("MyObject");
item->doSomething();
```